# Calculate difference based on FK and date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a select in MySQL in order to calculate the difference of the orders placed by customers based on the month or dates using the FK(customerID) as reference of the **FIRST TABLE** below.

What I would like to do is to list the difference as shown below for **customerID** **84** and **92**

**FIRST TABLE**

```
id         order_month      order_date          order      customerID
24          08              2012-08-14           24            84
58          08              2012-08-19           12            84
27          08              2012-08-12           18            84
85          09              2012-09-12           9             92
120         09              2012-09-14           14            92
124         09              2012-09-19           44            92
164         09              2012-09-20           28            92
```

**For customerID = 84**

```
id         order_month      order_date          order    order_diff     customerID
24          08              2012-08-14           24          +12           84
58          08              2012-08-19           12          -6            84
27          08              2012-08-12           18          +18           84
```

**For customerID = 92**

```
85          09              2012-09-12           9           -5            92
120         09              2012-09-14           14         -30            92
124         09              2012-09-19           44         -16            92
164         09              2012-09-20           28         +28            92
```

I am trying to achieve the result above using following SELECT:

```
SELECT a.id, a.order, (b.order - a.order) AS 'Difference' FROM custOrder a 
INNER JOIN custOrder b ON b.id = (a.id + 1) 
WHERE b.customerID = 84 AND b.order_month = 08  
ORDER BY b.order_date ASC
```

Unfortunately the select does not produce the result I would like to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things not making sense to me. Is this record for **customer 84** what you expect or what you're getting that you don't expect?

```
id         order_month      order_date          order    order_diff     customerID
24          08              2012-08-14           24          +12           84
```

Because I don't see how you get to +12, when the next order `id` after `24` is `27` and looking at those amounts I get either: `24 - 18 = +6` or `18 - 24 = -6`. How are you expecting to get +12?

Yes, *visually* there is a record in between those two with id `58`, but you absolutely cannot rely on the order that the records happen to have in the database. That is completely arbitrary and changes as the optimizer sees fit.

I can give you this query to get you started, it selects the next row of that customer and month and subtracts the order amount from the current one if it finds a next record.

```
SELECT a.id, a.order_month, a.order_date, a.order,
    (a.order - ifnull(b.order, 0)) AS 'Difference', a.customerID
FROM custOrder a 
LEFT JOIN custOrder b ON b.id = (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM custOrder 
    WHERE id > a.id
      AND customerID = a.customerID
      AND order_month = a.order_month
) 
ORDER BY a.order_date ASC
```

Working **[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78a7d/9/0)**

So I'm joining `custOrder b` where the `id` is the smallest (`MIN()`) but still larger then `a.id` (`>`). That effectively gives me the *"next"* record. As well the `customerID` and `order_month` need to be the same as the values in `custOrder a`.